# HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized using urllib.request.urlopen

Tags: python, teamcity

I'm using urllib.request in python to try and download some build information from Teamcity. This request used to work without username and password, however a recent security change means I must use a username and password. So I have changed tried each of the two solutions below:

Attempt 1)

```
url = 'http://<domain>/httpAuth/app/rest/buildTypes/<buildlabel>/builds/running:false?count=1&start=0'

# create a password manager
password_mgr = urllib.request.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()

# Add the username and password.
top_level_url = "http://<domain>/httpAuth/app/rest/buildTypes/id:<buildlabel>/builds/running:false?count=1&start=0"
password_mgr.add_password(None, top_level_url, username, password)

handler = urllib.request.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(password_mgr)

# create "opener" (OpenerDirector instance)
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(handler)

# use the opener to fetch a URL
opener.open(url)
```

Attempt 2

```
url = 'http://<username>:<password>@<domain>/httpAuth/app/rest/buildTypes/id:buildlabel/builds/running:false?count=1&start=0'
rest_api = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
```

Both of these return "HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized". However if I was to print 'url' and copy this output into a browser the link works perfectly. But when used through python I get the above error.

I use something very similar in another Perl script and this works perfectly also.

*** SOLVED BELOW ***

Comment: server may check other elements - like HTTP headers, cookies, etc. You can use DevTools in Chrome/Firefox to check what browser sends to server - ie. HTTP headers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved this using.

```
credentials(url, username, password)
rest_api = urllib2.urlopen(url)
latest_build_info = rest_api.read()
latest_build_info = latest_build_info.decode("UTF-8")
# Then parse this xml for the information I want. 

def credentials(self, url, username, password):
    p = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
    p.add_password(None, url, username, password)
    handler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(p)
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(handler)
    urllib2.install_opener(opener)
```

As a side note, I then want to download a file..

```
credentials(url, username, password)
urllib2.urlretrieve(url, downloaded_file)
```

Where Url is:

```
http://<teamcityServer>/repository/download/<build Label>/<BuildID>:id/Filename.zip
```

Comment: urllib2 does not have a urlretrieve method? That would be plain ol' urllib